# Yii2 baseUrl bundle asset in the view

Tags: yii2

In the layout file I have

```
$bundle=MyAsset::register($this);
```

but I don't know how to use `$bundle->baseUrl` in the view.
`$bundle->baseUrl` works corretly in the layout but if I use it in a view I have a `Undefined variable: bundle`.

Comment: If previous answers for your questions have helped  out please consider accepting one of those.

Comment: register the asset in the view instead of the layout

Answer (score 0):

As the view is the the [yii\web\View](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html) object you can access the [assetBundles](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#$assetBundles-detail) and their baseUrls with inside the view files:

```
$this->assetBundles['yourAssetBundleName']->baseUrl;
```

Just for the sake of completeness, if its needed to access image paths within a bundle, you maybe better put them inside the `public_html` / `webroot` folder as they are visible to the web anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do

```
$bundle=MyAsset::register($this);
```

in the view, as well.

As described in the [Issue Tracker](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/3566#issuecomment-44008949), Yii will not replace the AssetBundle registered in the layout.